# Pig comparision operator not working in GENERATE

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

using pig from the command line I can use

b = filter a by (desc matches '.*XZY*.');

and get results I expect ....

however when I use

c = foreach a GENERATE (desc matches '.*RFNC*.'?'yes':'no');

I get all 'no'

Do I have a syntax issue or is this statement not legal inside of GENERATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your matches code should be something like below:

```
c = foreach a GENERATE desc matches '.*RFNC.*' ? 'yes' : 'no' as match_result;
```

for more info check [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/basic.html#comparison)